# How to load textures from OBJ+MTL files in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have a Maya file exported to OBJ and MTL. I can see the OBJ texture successfully, but how do I actually get the texture in? I looked at the "three.js" format in blender, which appears to be shape only, no texture.

This [three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html) appears to load in the obj fine for the shape, but the texture appears to come from a jpg image and not an mtl:

```js
loader.load('textures/ash_uvgrid01.jpg', function(image) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
});
```

My question is, how do I get this "uvgrid01.jpg" image for my model? Is there some way to convert MTL to this .jpg format for the texture only? Or is there some other way I should be exporting the texture to be able to load it in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use OBJLoader and MTLLoader, as seen in [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/3510fdd91725f7681db845efd889c5e29e6e7446/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html) (at least three.js r77):

```js
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath('obj/male02/');
mtlLoader.load('male02_dds.mtl', function(materials) {
  materials.preload();
  var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
  objLoader.setPath('obj/male02/');
  objLoader.load('male02.obj', function(object) {
    object.position.y = -95;
    scene.add(object);
  }, onProgress, onError);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer true, as OBJMTLLoader has been [removed](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js) from THREE.js

Comment: @nachteil It was split into 2 loaders, the example has been updated.